# Trying to update some field does not work in Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

*** I tried to update some field of my database from my page but when i tried it doesn't update the element just delete it, i don't know why the element gets destroyed and not update it, how can i solve it***

- Below i will let the code that doesn't update the information and my `index function()` because the code is inside os that function,also my model `Entrada` and my table `Entrada`

*** `index function` ***

```php
public function index(Request $request,$id_entrada,$id_venta_entrada,$id_costo,$correo)
    {   
        $detalle_entrada=new Detalle_venta_entrada();
        $detalle_entrada->precio=$id_costo;
        $detalle_entrada->fk_venta_entrada=$id_venta_entrada;
        $detalle_entrada->fk_entrada=$id_entrada;
        $detalle_entrada->save();
        $ventas=new Venta();
        $ventas->monto_total=$id_costo;
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $ventas->fecha_venta=$now->format('d-m-Y');
        $ventas->fk_cliente_natural=1;
        $sub = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT precio_entrada from entrada WHERE id_entrada='$id_entrada'"));
        $subtotal = $sub[0]->precio_entrada;
        $monto = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT precio from detalle_venta_entrada WHERE fk_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada'"));
        $monto_total = $monto[0]->precio;
        $ventas->save();
        $id = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT Max(id_venta) as venta_id from venta"));
        $id_venta = $id[0]->venta_id;
        Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->update(array(
            'disponible'=>'true',
        ));
        $detalle_venta_entrada = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT id_detalle_entrada,precio,
                                                    (select numero_entrada from entrada where id_entrada='$id_entrada'),
                                                    (select fecha from venta_entrada where id_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada'),
                                                    (select monto_total from venta_entrada where id_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada' and fk_cliente_natural=1),
                                                    (select primer_nombre from cliente_natural where id_cliente_natural=1)
                                                    FROM detalle_venta_entrada WHERE fk_venta_entrada='$id_venta_entrada'and fk_entrada='$id_entrada'"));
        return view ('home.misOrdenes')->with('detalle_venta_entrada',$detalle_venta_entrada)
                                       ->with('id_entrada',$id_entrada)
                                       ->with('id_venta_entrada',$id_venta_entrada)
                                       ->with('detalle_entrada',$detalle_entrada)
                                       ->with('subtotal',$subtotal)
                                       ->with('monto_total',$monto_total)
                                       ->with('id_venta',$id_venta)
                                       ->with('correo',$correo);
    }
```

*** code that doesn't update ***

```php
Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->update(array(
            'disponible'=>'true',
        ));
```

***This is my table `Entrada` ***

```sql
create table Entrada(
        ID_Entrada serial,
        Numero_Entrada integer not null,
        Precio_Entrada real not null,
        Disponible boolean not null,
        FK_Evento integer not null,
        constraint pk_ID_Entrada primary key (ID_Entrada),
        constraint fk_FK_Evento_Entrada foreign key(FK_Evento) references Evento(ID_Evento) on delete cascade on update cascade
    );
```

***Model `Entrada` ***

```php
class Entrada extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_entrada';
    protected $table = 'entrada';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['id_entrada','numero_entrada','precio_entrada','disponible','fk_evento'];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Comment: Please check if Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->first() is returning an instance. It will only update if the where clause matches any records

Comment: May i know that, are you getting the values in variable `$id_costo`.

Comment: Yes i got the value of the varible `$id_costo`

Comment: I checked ` if Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->first()` and works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works, the thing was i didn't notice that when i update the Entrada send it to the bottom of the list in my bd so i thought it didn't work because i have a lot of registers and change the position of the updated one

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below: and see if it works.

```
$detalle_entrada = new Detalle_venta_entrada();
$detalle_entrada->precio = $request->get('id_costo');
$detalle_entrada->fk_venta_entrada = $request->get('id_venta_entrada');
$detalle_entrada->fk_entrada = $request->get('id_entrada');
$detalle_entrada->save();
```

Comment: i wrote this code as i have doubt if you are getting the values in `index()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have included the "Entrada" model on top of the class. If no then include it first, because you have explicitly created new instance for "Detalle_venta_entrada" and "Venta" and not for "Entrada"

Make sure the $id_entrada attribute value is properly passed to this method or not

Try the following code in a tinker first

```
php artisan tinker
```

`Entrada::where('id_entrada', $id_entrada)->first();` ([] is not needed when you have a single where condition, hence removed).

If you get the result, then update it.

Always have a condition before you update any data.

eg)

```
$entradaData = Entrada::where('id_entrada', $id_entrada)->first();
if(filled($entradaData))
{
  Entrada::where('id_entrada', $id_entrada)->update(
        ['disponible'=>'true']
    );
}
```

Comment: When i put it on tinker said this `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id_entrada in Psy Shell code on line 1`

Comment: Tinker is helpful to get a preview before we write any code Entrada::where('id_entrada',  3)->first();  replace 3 with the actual value of $id_entrada..

Answer (score -1):

```
Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->update(array(
        'disponible'=>'true',
    ));`
```

Try the code below:

```
$response = Entrada::where(['id_entrada'=>$id_entrada])->first();
$response->disponible = 'true';
$response->update();
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does. $response->update(); will do literally nothing to the model instance in that code.

Comment: @AhmedShefeer you should cross check, it will update current fetched records.